# No suitable driver found for～でデータベースに接続出来ない

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

現在データベースに接続する部分で下記エラーが出力されます。

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/oo

原因を調査した結果、
・JDBCドライバのjarのクラスパスが設定されていない
・JDBCドライバが適切な場所にない
のどちらかなのかなと考えました。

そこでまず、JDBCドライバのjarについて調査した結果、
JDBCドライバのjar＝mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar
なのかなと考え、eclipse上で外部jarの追加から上記jarを追加しましたが、
結果は変わりませんでした。
現在は、JDBCドライバのjarについて調査している段階です。

```js
　
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/oo";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "oo";

        try{

            //「↓この処理でエラー発生：No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/oo」
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name from mst");

            while ( rs.next() ) {
                String user_name = rs.getString("name");
            }

        }catch
```

このエラーの解決方法について分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: 接続手前で `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` を実行してエラーが出るでしょうか？

Comment: conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
この部分でエラーが出力されます

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mattn様ご指摘の通り、Class.forName()を追加すれば問題なく読み込めるかと存じます。
念のためmysql-connector-java-5.0.4.jarで検証はしました。

```
Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/oo";
String user = "root";
String password = "oo";

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    // 以降省略....
}
```

conn = DriverManager... の箇所でエラーが出ているとのことですが、出力したエラー内容は以前と同じでしょうか。もしエラー内容が変わっていればドライバの読み込みは正しいですので、url、user、passwordが正しいものであるかをご確認ください。

参考となるサイト：http://www.javadrive.jp/servlet/database/

Comment: ありがとうございます。
エラーを解消することが出来ました